# Unable to get string response from Spring mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been working on a Spring based web project. Most of the endpoints are set to return XML, and they work just fine using a REST marshaller. As part of the project demonstration, I'd like to have a dashboard that displays the data in a more human readable format.

Problem is, I can't get the endpoint to return a String. When I try to access the endpoint, I get the following error message:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 406 -

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000126: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request 'Accept' headers.
```

The mapping request code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dash", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*",produces="text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String customerPortal()
{
  return "WEB-INF/jsp/Dash.jsp";
}
```

The other (XML) endpoints work just fine, and the file itself exists. At this point, I'd settle for any way to transmit HTML to the browser, I don't need anything fancy, just a single file that won't run afoul of the AJAX single origin restrictions. I apologize if there's an easy solution to this, I've tried half a dozen different solutions and cannot find any way to get the server to send anything but XML.

Edit: After removing the @ResponseBody, method, headers, and produces annotations, it now gives the following response:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - Could not resolve view with name '/WEB-INF/jsp/ScorpioDash.jsp' in servlet with name 'scorpio-restservice'

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

JBWEB000068: message Could not resolve view with name '/WEB-INF/jsp/ScorpioDash.jsp' in servlet with name 'scorpio-restservice'

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/WEB-INF/jsp/ScorpioDash.jsp' in servlet with name 'scorpio-restservice'
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Comment: What `Accept` headers are you sending in requests to `/dash`?

Comment: This method returns the name of a view to which Spring must forward. So what it returns is not the response body. So it shouldn't be annotated withResponseBody.

Comment: Plus you are most likely not returning the correct string to forward to the view (depending on how you have setup your view resolver)

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know what the accept headers are. I'm trying to access it from the browser, if that's any help. As for the response body, I'm literally fishing for any kind of response. I want, in some way, to get the servlet to return ANYTHING that can be displayed by the browser. It doesn't need to be pretty, I just need to get it to work.

Comment: Remove the `headers` from the `@Requestmapping` and you can focus on the other potential problems mentioned above.

Comment: And also remove the `produces` attribute. The JSP will tell what the content type is, and it will probably be text/html.

Comment: After removing those annotations, it now gives the following: HTTP Status 500 - Could not resolve view with name '/WEB-INF/jsp/Dash.jsp' in servlet with name 'scorpio-restservice'

Comment: The question is sort of confusing, what exactly are you trying to return; can you supply a small example mock of what you expect to see? The @ResponseBody indicates that you want to return the results of the method as the http response body. Hence if you simply annotate as `@RequestMapping(value="/dash", method=RequestMethod.GET` you will get the String "WEB-INF/jsp/Dash.jsp" as your http response. 

Are you trying to return the contents of the Dash.jsp as html?

Comment: I'm literally willing to accept ANYTHING. I'd like to see the contents of the file, but if it would just return the string I'd be fine with it. I can load the HTML file manually if need be, I just need a response that can be rendered by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. In the scorpio-restservice-servlet.xml file (which I did not post, sorry) I hadn't defined an InternalResourceViewResolver. Adding the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/static/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Fixed the problem and got it to render .jsp files beautifully. Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: This only works after your remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation. It's important you add that in your answer.

Comment: Correct, that is why I was asking about what the expected result was. Getting a JSP to render is quite different than seeing the contents of a file.

Comment: You should also set a prefix on the resolver to avoid having to do the full `WEB-INF/jsp` path in the controller.